# How to build an XPath parse tree in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, xpath

I need to be able to understand the contents of specific XPath statements provided as data, which I realize is kind of unusual.

Rather than build a full-fledged XPath statement parser or fall back to regular expressions (since XPath is recursive), I was hoping there would be a Ruby XML library out there with an implementation that provides the root of an XPath parse tree.  It looks like `Nokogiri` does not.  Is there a Ruby library that does?  Several searches suggest that the results are going to be about evaluating XPath statements against specific XML documents, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The parser described here looks like a toy rather than a product, but it might be a starting point: https://linuxtut.com/en/11daaa8daab9b6d94a15/

Answer (score 1):

If XPath 1.0 is enough for you then you can use REXML's XPath parser, no gem is needed.

```rb
require 'rexml/parsers/xpathparser.rb'

xpath_parser = REXML::Parsers::XPathParser.new
xpath_parser.parse('//guests/person[@id="jane doe"]')
#=> [:document, :descendant_or_self, :node, :child, :qname, "", "guests", :child, :qname, "", "person", :predicate, [:eq, [:attribute, :qname, "", "id"], [:literal, "jane doe"]]]
```